# Page is not found

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have the following urls:

```
urlspatterns=[  path('<str:urlsername>/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(),name ='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view()),
    path('password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(),name='password_change'),]
```

In views for the first url I have this:

```
def profile(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username = username)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(author = user).order_by('-pub_date')
    return render(request,'profile.html', {'posts':posts,'user':user})
```

So when I go to the page login, logout or password_change I get the error "Page is not found"

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/password_change/
Raised by:  posts.views.profile
```

But if I comment the profile view and its url everything works just fine. Why does the url 'logout' etc goes to profile view?

Comment: There's something in your Question that is that  nobody can't understand. AND i think you should upload your full views.py for better clarification of the Question.

Answer (score 1):

I think `password_change` will match `<str:urlsername>` first.
So the solution is change your urlspatterns to the code bellow.

```py
urlspatterns=[  
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(),name ='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view()),
    path('password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(),name='password_change'),
    path('<str:urlsername>/', views.profile, name='profile')
]
```